# Ошибка при записи строки в массив

Tags: c#, xml

Получаю я данные из XML и хочу их записать в массив.

Но у меня выдает ошибку:

> Additional information: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Сам код:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText("company.xml"));
XmlNodeList fullNames = xml.SelectNodes("/КоммерческаяИнформация/ОрганизационнаяСтруктура/Работники/Работник/Наименование");
XmlNodeList nodelogins = xml.SelectNodes("/КоммерческаяИнформация/ОрганизационнаяСтруктура/Работники/Работник/Логин");

// Собираю логины из XML
int i = 0;
string[] loginArr = null;
foreach (XmlNode nodelogin in nodelogins) 
{
    loginArr[i] = nodelogin.InnerText; i++;
}
MessageBox.Show(loginArr[0]);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не создали массив `loginArr`. У вас он является null-ссылкой. Поэтому вы не можете использовать оператор индексации. Ни память для элементов массива не выделена, ни сам размер массива неизвестен.

```
string[] loginArr = null;
foreach (XmlNode nodelogin in nodelogins) 
{
    loginArr[i] = nodelogin.InnerText; i++;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Вам сначала нужно определить, сколько элементов содержится в `nodelogins`  и на основе этого значения выделить память для элементов массива `loginArr` с помощью оператора `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Массиву нужно задавать размерность.

```
var loginArr = new string[nodelogins.Count];
```

Можно сделать через список:

```
var loginArr = new List<string>{};
foreach (XmlNode nodelogin in nodelogins) 
{
    loginArr.Add(nodelogin.InnerText);
}
```